# Функция jQuery

Tags: jquery

Как написать функцию для jQuery добавляющую событие ondrag ко всем элементам набора?
Определение функции написал, а обход по элементам не знаю как реализовать..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function(){
   var elements = $(".some-class"); //Берем элементы
   elements.each(function(){ //Пробегаим их по очереди
      this.bind("ondrag", function(){...}); //Добавляем каждому обработчик
   });
});
```

Comment: К сожалению .bind не добавляет DOM-овские события

Answer (score 4):

```
(function (b) {
    b.fn.MyFn = function () {
        return this.each(function () {
            //элемент: b(this)
            //ваш код
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```